# How can I see the elements inside iframe documents like Firebug does?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, firebug

I am using an `<iframe>` in my HTML document.

When I view the source code in the browser via the *View Source* option I cannot see the elements inside the `<iframe>`. However when I inspect the source code in Firebug I can see all the elements in iframe.

Is there are way to echo the entire HTML structure like Firebug shows it to the console via JavaScript, e.g. using jQuery?

Comment: check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777316/read-iframe-content-using-javascript] link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`console.dirxml(window.frames[i].document)`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.dirxml) with `i` being the index of your `<iframe>`.

Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

Right click into the `<iframe>` and choose *This Frame* > *View Frame Source*. (At least that's how you can do it in Firefox.)

Comment: No, I meant I want to print it in the console Like console.log()