# How to get innerHTML of iframe

Tags: iframe

<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/terimariedegree" data-format="inline" data-width="300" data-related="false"></script>

Comment: You need to provide some other context, are you looking for a solution in javascript, php, asp.net jquery... Or are you expecting us to do this for you in every possible language so that you can pick? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777316/read-iframe-content-using-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read IFrame content using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777316/read-iframe-content-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Please refine your answer, also you might want to lookup https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp